# Change formatting on specific parts of text with TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea, flash-cs5

I have a little bit of a problem here. I am making a kind of chat application in Flash CS5, using Action Script 3, and I am trying to make URLs that appear in the main chat textbox (where all of the things that other people have said come up), which is a TextArea component, be converted into HTML link tags. I have this working, but the problem I am facing now is that the links appear black. I want them to appear with an underline, and blue text. I am formatting the TextArea with `TextFormat`, and I am using some of the functionality that is only available in TextAreas, so I cannot use plain dynamic labels.
I have also tried using the `style` attribute of the link tag, but that didn't do anything.

How can I change the formatting for the link tags to appear blue and with an underline?

My current code for changing the links to HTML link tags looks like this:

```
txtOutput.htmlText += replace(/(?:http|https):\/\/\S*/g, function ():String
{
    return '<a href="' + arguments[0] + '">' + arguments[0] + '</a>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [style sheets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) you can implement hyperlink styles form there.
**update:**
The textArea has a textField property. try applying he style sheet to that.

Comment: I tried stylesheets but the TextArea compontent does not support them. As far as I know it only supports `TextFormat`.

Comment: are you using flex? or is this the Flash component?

Comment: grab the internal textField by using TextArea.textField property, and apply styleSheet. Both Flex and Flash verstions have this property

Comment: @niel_manuell This is the Flash compontent. I will try the `styleSheet` property, but just wondering... will `TextFormat` and `styleSheet` work in conjunction?